# Magento Custom field in order grid

Tags: php, orders, sales-order

I want to add a custom column in magento order grid which should have a input field to populate. This is for screen purpose only so that agent can see information quickly and populate it.

**customer Need extra accessories** column

**input field** (Agent can write yes or no whatever) Like this below

[image]

So, I want a idea that from where i can start?

Answer (score 1):

jessay,This case you can use rendered concept.

1. Rewrite class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid`.
2. _`prepareColumns` function add yourfield

> protected function _prepareColumns()
>       {         $this->addColumnAfter('customer_id', array(             'header'           => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Title'),           'align'            => 'center',             'renderer'         =>
>   'Mymoduleblockoprefix/adminhtml_sales_order_renderer_myfield',
>             'index'            => 'customer_id',        ),'shipping_name');
>
> ```
>     parent::_prepareColumns();
>     return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
>
> }
> ```

3.Then using  rendered at you can add button on which updta the data

```
<?php
classMyNameSpace_Mymodule_PhoneForOrderGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Myfield
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Input
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $html = parent::render($row);

        $html .= '<button onclick="updateField(this, '. $row->getId() .'); return false">' . Mage::helper('sales')->__('Update') . '</button>';

        return $html;
    }

}
```

Create  admin layout in where you have write  JavaScript.... which call ajax request which you can update the field
put your layout file into app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/namespace/ folder with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_modulename_index>
        <reference name="js">
            <block type="core/template" template="namespace/modulename/inline-edit.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_modulename_index>
</layout>
```

By using  we are adding a new block to  block defined in main.xml layout of the backend. And because it has type of core/text_list it will render all of its child blocks automatically Finally lets create template file with our JavaScript logic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTitle(button, fieldId)
{
    new Ajax.Request('<?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('*/*/updateTitle') ?>', {
        method: 'post',
        parameters: { id: fieldId, title: $(button).previous('input').getValue() }
    });
}
</script>
```

See more at http://www.atwix.com/magento/inline-editing-in-magento-backend-grids/

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about the grid on admin page `Sales -> Orders`, then you can copy this file:

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

to here:

app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

And then only modify the file in your local folder.

If you look at the _prepareColumns method, you can see there are calls to `$this->addColumn`.  You can add your own columns this way.

And then if you want an edit box in each row, you can try using `'type' => 'edit'`, I think that's the correct type name.

Comment: Yes i am taking about sales > orders and these two files are same!

Comment: Copying files to the local namespace to adjust functionality is not good practice. You will be setting yourself up for fail one day you want to upgrade core to new version. Prefer to extend